# Is there keyboard input that isn't considered a char?

Tags: c++, validation, input

Thanks for taking the time to read this first of all,

I'm currently writing a driver program for a class in C++ and I need some input from the user. I've started using `typedef` to create validation programs so I can switch between different types fairly easily. For the particular problem I'm working on, I've found that I'm only working with `char` which leads me to my questions:

1. My validation checks to see if the input is `char`. Is using validation  pointless if I know I'm just working with `char` in particular? Everything that the user types in seems to be a char.
2. Is there anything that the user could type in that won't be considered a `char`?

This question may seem a bit trivial but I've never really thought about this before! Still learning the language, so any guidance is appreciated.

Code in question (ElementType is of type `char`):

```
void getInput( ElementType & cho )
{
    while ( !(cin >> cho) )
    {
        cout<< "That is an invalid input..."
            << "\nTry again: ";
    }
    cout<< endl;
}
```

Comment: This is all very vague. Your terminology is not accurate enough to properly answer this without seeing code.

Comment: Presumably you mean "a logical character whose internal representation is formed of a single 8-bit byte encoding a 7-bit or 8-bit value", not `char`. That's not pedanticism: the two are _completely_ different, and the difference is crucial when you're talking about this kind of thing.

Comment: Can you clarify your question.  The `cin` stream is defined as inputting a sequence of `char` objects, therefore any input is `char` by definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anything that the user could type in that won't be considered a char?

Yes: <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> to name a few.

The point is that a keyboard is its own beast with a potential output for each key-press, key-release of every key.  A keyboard driver (software) takes these events and translates them into a series of `char` for a program's `cin/stdin`.  Alternatively, a program could get access to the low level events, but may be beyond standard C++ code.

Recommend staying with the model that `cin` receives sporadically *any* of the usually 256 different `char` including `'\0'` until program-end or `cin` is closed from *some* source be it a keyboard, re-directed file input, piped input, or a remote device.  Ignore that idea that input *usually* comes from a keyboard.  It is simply a sequence of `char`.

> Is using validation pointless?

Validation is useful.  Code should validate the `char` arriving per the requirements of the *program* - not the requirements of `char`.  Example, code may have trouble handing a null character, a negative `char`, a `char` outside the ASCII range of 0 - 127, or too many `char` between line endings.  Validating input makes code resilient against hackers who will exploit a vulnerable program.

Answer (score -1):

Under Linux, with UTF-8 input, I can certainly type a lot of stuff that isn't a `char`. E.g. typing `á` gives two bytes. There are quite a lot of others, directly typeable depending on the keyboard handling in place.

International character handling is *complex*. Not all the world types ASCII.

Comment: Right, but IOStreams read `char`s. It doesn't matter that your UTF-8 character is composed of two bytes: C++ doesn't read UTF-8. It reads bytes. It _always_ reads `char`. So, can you pass anything into C++ that "isn't a `char`"? No. Does it make sense to "validate that the input is a `char`"? No; you cannot "validate" the type system. (Replace `char` with `wchar_t` in the above as needed; I'm making an assumption on the extraction method here, which is another point: we have to, because the question is not answerable in its current form.)

Comment: Could you explain what you're referring to by "extraction method" so I can better pose the question?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, yes, C++ reads octets (also called "bytes"), but those aren't characters. The type used by C/C++ to store octets is (misleadingly) called `char`. Contrast with [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_(computing)), in particular look for the definition of the term in the [Unicode standard](http://unicode.org/standard/standard.html).